# semaphores.h and threads.h in c

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

Hallo i need to install  and  libs for c.I am using a linux ubuntu o/s.Does anybody knows how i can install them?

Comment: What do you want to do? Libs for semaphores? Libs for threads? Read about posix semaphores and pthreads. Most likely, both alredy available.

Comment: Sorry, voted to close this and _then_ may have figured out what you meant :)

Answer (score 3):

Try: `sudo apt-get install build-essential`, that should produce a working tool chain. If you need cross compilers, update your question and I'll post a very, very long shell script to install them.

Comment: +1; this will get you other things you probably need later on. The files `semaphore.h` and `pthread.h` are in `libc6-dev`, which you should have for any C development anyhow.